# Evaluating integral with Legendre polynomials

Tags: special-functions

I want to do the following integral:

$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1} x^n P_{n}(x) \rm{d}x
$$

WITHOUT using Rodrigues' formula.
I'm required to use

$$
P_{n}(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{[n/2]} \frac{(-1)^r (2n-2r)!}{2^n r! (n-r)! (n-2 r)!} x^{n-2 r}.
$$

Substituing $ P_{n}(x) $ into I, I got

$$
I = 2 \sum_{r=0}^{[n/2]} \frac{ (-1)^{r} (2n-2r)!}{2^n r! (n-r)!(n-2r)!(2n-2r+1)}
$$

, but I don't know how I can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the fact that the set of Legendre polynomials $P_n$  form an orthogonal base for all polynomials of degree less or equal to n, we can state that
$$x^n = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j P_j(x)$$
The coefficients $b_j$ can be derived by using the internal product defined on functions on $[-1, 1]$:
$$b_j = \int_{-1}^1 x^n P_j(x)dx$$
$P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, so we can write
$$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$

The highest order term has coefficient $b_n$ and that is the one you are looking for initially. If we decompose $x^n$ into a linear combination of $P_n, P_{n-1}, ..., P_1$, starting with the highest order term thus trying to find the factor that $P_n$ has to be multiplied with, it is clear that this is equal to $1/a_n$.

This value can be derived to be equal to
$$b_n = \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{2^nn!^2}{(2n)!} =\frac{n!}{1\cdot3\cdot\cdot\cdot(2n-3)(2n-1)}$$
which you can also derive from the formula you gave, by looking at the term with $r=0$.

See for instance ([Choice of the First Term in Legendre Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577374/choice-of-the-first-term-in-legendre-polynomials/766225#766225)). Note that there the highest order term of $P_n(x)$ has been given a coefficient named $a_0$, but that is our $a_n$ here.