# Choice of the First Term in Legendre Polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials

The two solutions of the Legendre's Differential Equation obtained by series solution method are :

[image]

and

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Now according to my textbook, *for the **useful polynomial** for **n** equal to a positive integer, the constant **$a_{0}$** in the first case is chosen as $a_{0}={\frac{1.3.5...(2n-1)}{n!}}$ and the solution is then called Legendre's polyinomial or coffecient or Zonal Harmonics of the first kind.*

*For **n** being the negative integer the constant **$a_{0}$** in the second case is chosen as $a_{0}={\frac{n!}{1.3.5...(2n+1)}}$ and the corresponding polynomial is defined as Legendre's function of the second kind.*

**Now the choice of *$a_{0}$* seems rather arbitrary and exactly how is such a choice useful?**

P.S.: While solving the Hermite Equation we choose *$a_{0}$*  in a similar (and apparently) arbitrary manner. Is the reason behind the choice somehow related?

The complete solution of Legendre's equation using series solution method can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_Differential_Equation)

Comment: I have a _gut feeling_ that the constants were chosen in such a way, so that terms were identical to those obtained using the generating function. But I can not find any credible source to back my intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in fact not $a_0$ for which a value is chosen. For Legendre polynomials $P_n$, the "normalization" is to set $P_n(1) = 1$. That choice leads to Rodrigues' formula
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}$$
from which we derive
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_n(x) &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x+1)^n\cdot(x-1)^n]^{(n)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}[(x+1)^n]^{(k)} \cdot [(x-1)^n]^{(n-k)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x+1)^{n-k} \cdot \frac{n!}{k!}(x-1)^k
\\ &= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2(x+1)^{n-k}(x-1)^k
\end{split}
\end{equation}

so 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_0 &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!^2}
\\ &= \frac{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot2\cdot 1}{2^n\cdot n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot2\cdot 1 \cdot n!}
\\ &= \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\cdot\cdot3\cdot 1}{n!}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which is exactly the value you found in your textbook.